# How to remove a sprite permanently in Cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I am developing a game using cocos2d-x. I want to remove sprites permanently. I have two sprites & making collision between the sprites. When collision happens, i want to remove those sprites permanently. I am using the following code to making collision & remove sprites.

```
CCARRAY_FOREACH(_sprrand24, stwentyfour)
{
    CCSize size=sprrand24->getContentSize();            
    CCSprite *sprrand24 = dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>(stwentyfour);
    CCRect sprrand24Rect = CCRectMake( 
                                           sprrand24->getPosition().x - (size.width/2),
                                           sprrand24->getPosition().y - (size.height/2),
                                           size.width/2,
                                           size.height/2);
   CCARRAY_FOREACH(_sprrand25, stwentyfive)
   {
       CCSize size=sprrand25->getContentSize();
       CCSprite *sprrand25 = dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>(stwentyfive);
       CCRect sprrand25Rect = CCRectMake(
                                           sprrand25->getPosition().x - (size.width/2),
                                           sprrand25->getPosition().y - (size.height/2),
                                           size.width/2,  
                                           size.height/2);

   if (sprrand24Rect.intersectsRect(sprrand25Rect))
   {
    this->removeChild(sprrand24, true);
    this->removeChild(sprrand25, true);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the sprite you can use

```
 sprrand24.removeFromParentAndCleanup(true);
```

Comment: I use schedule to call the function(collision) repeatedly. So after i made collision, it is removed but not permanently. I am adding a score  50 after i made collision. Once collision is happened it is keep on increasing 50+. I want to add 50 only once.

Answer (score 0):

if you assign each of your Sprites a `tag`, you can then do `removeChildByTag(tag);`

```
sprite->setTag(99); // i made this up


this->removeChildByTag(99);
```

Comment: I use schedule to call the function(collision) repeatedly. So after i made collision, it is removed but not permanently. I am getting following output repeatedly n number of times.                                                Cocos2d: cocos2d: removeChildByTag(tag = 1): child not found!
Cocos2d: cocos2d: removeChildByTag(tag = 11): child not found!

Comment: why are you doing `removeChildByTag(tag=1)`, it should be just `removeChildByTag(1)`